# Can't use TextInputDialog in Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx-8

I'm trying to run a program that uses the JavaFX scene object TextInputDialog. For some reason, it doesn't allow me to import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog (says "cannot be resolved").

I'm new to JavaFX, but here is what I tried. I thought it was my Java version, so I updated to the latest (1.8.0_91). I'm using Eclipse Neon 4.6.0. To install JavaFX it used the "install new software" option in the help menu, and put in the link found in step 4 of this: https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html. After that, most of the JavaFX functions worked by adding the requisite import command. But this one doesn't.

I also found that some people have included the JavaFX library in the build path. I didn't change anything when I did that (though I'm not sure exactly what that would do since I already installed JavaFX in Eclipse).

Anyway, any suggestions would be very welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that eclipse is using the newer JRE for this project.  You can do this by going to `Project > Properties > Java Build Path` and selecting the newer JRE from the list.  I believe it needs to be 1.8.0_45 or newer.

Comment: For some reason, even after changing the java path to the 1.8.0_91 and install that version of java, THEN installing Eclipse, it still was pointing to the 1.8.0_25 version. I had to go in and manually point Eclipse to the new JDK folder. Pretty fragile if you ask me. Anyway, it's fixed. Even though I knew that was a requirement, I'll still mark this is as the solution since it made me double check. Thanks.

Comment: It is a bit touchy.  I have had many issues with this in the past, but I am glad you got it to work.